# Providing a delegate to resolving registered open generics in Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have an interface like this:

```
ICreator<T> {}
```

What I want to do is let a user resolve the dependency like this:

```
var creator = container.Resolve<ICreator<IUser>>();
```

The trick is that I want to be able to do some custom creation of the concrete type for `ICreator<T>`. In my case, I have a `Creator<T, TConcrete>` with a constructor that takes a type with a generic that uses `TConcrete`. By convention I know what the type for `TConcrete` should be given the `T` defined in `ICreator`, but `RegisterGeneric` doesn't seem like it gives me what I need, which is a delegate to create the `Creator<,>` instance.

Or maybe this does exist in Autofac and I'm missing it? Any insight would be appreciated - TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a particular creator for concrete type. Sample:

```
public interface ICreator<T>
{
    void WriteName();
}

public class Creator<T> : ICreator<T>
{
    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm standard creator: " + typeof(T).FullName);
    }
}

public class CustomIntCreator : ICreator<int>
{
    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm custom int creator");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder cb = new ContainerBuilder();
        cb.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Creator<>)).As(typeof (ICreator<>));
        cb.RegisterType<CustomIntCreator>().As<ICreator<int>>();
        var container = cb.Build();

        var intCreator = container.Resolve<ICreator<int>>();            
        var standardCreator = container.Resolve<ICreator<double>>(); 
        intCreator.WriteName(); //writes "I'm custom int creator"
        standardCreator.WriteName(); //writes "I'm standard creator: System.Double"

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. What I'd like is to specify `ICreator<IThing>`, and return `Creator<IThing, Thing>`, where `Creator<IThing, Thing>` implements `ICreator<IThing>`. I can do this manually in code - `ICreator<IThing> creator = new Creator<IThing, Thing>()` - but I can't find a way to register this kind of configuration in Autofac.

Comment: One thing that does work is to hook `OnActivating` and call `ReplaceInstance`. That's pretty much what I'm looking for, but it has a small negative artifact in that it will create an instance of the generic type I provide in `RegisterGeneric`, which I'm going to replace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using `OnActivating` and `ReplaceInstance` are the necessary hooks to accomplish what I need:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FakeCreator<>)).As(typeof(ICreator<>)).OnActivating(args =>
    {
        // ...
        args.ReplaceInstance(new Creator<...,...>());
    });
```

It's not perfect as Autofac will create an instance of the configured generic type, but it works.